# unique visitor count not working with cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, ip-address

I am Beginner and want to learn how to count unique visitors by using PHP cookies. I tried to write this code. And also I am storing it in a database. The problem is I am not getting real visitors only 2-3 visitors came on this page according to google analytics, but according to my code, I am getting 50. this error is because of google bots?

I think the problem is in my code please help me to fix this.

Here is my code

```
      <?php 
    include 'configuration.php';
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
       if (preg_match('/bot|crawl|curl|dataprovider|search|get|spider|find|java|majesticsEO|google|yahoo|teoma|contaxe|yandex|libwww-perl|facebookexternalhit/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // is bot
}else{
$value = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
$path = "/";
$expires = time()+15780000;//6 month
$cookie =  '1';
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Q_zWnE8_aq']))
{
    $name= 'Q_zWnE8_aq';
    $new_visitor = $cookie++;
    setcookie($name, $value,$expires,$path,"mydomain.in");
    
    $sql010 = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM unique_vistor WHERE ip = ? ");
     $sql010->bind_param("s",$ip);
     $sql010->execute();
     
     
    $reS = $sql010->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(count($reS )>0){
    //   already exists
    }else{
   
            
            $result55=$conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO unique_vistor(id,name,value,expires,new_visitor,ip) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $result55->bind_param("isssss",$id,$name,$value,$expires,$new_visitor,$ip);
            $result55->execute();
            $result55->close();
            
        
    }

  }
}
        ?>
```

Comment: "mydomain.in" has to be in quotes.

Comment: Is $connection even defined?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE  I tried that also but getting same issue

Comment: Hi, You need a separate tables for IP logging and each visit should check against the ip table if exists or not.
Just cookie or session is not enough.

Comment: _Side note:_ An easier and better way to get a 20 char long unique string would be: `$value = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));`.

Comment: @AjmalPraveen - You should never use IP as any type of identifier. The same browser can access the same site from different IPs and many devices can access the site from the same IP.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I see , so is that above method is the right way for unique view count ? or Can you suggest a correct way to do ?

Comment: Can someone help to write correct way to count unique visitor using php cookies  and ip  address please?

Comment: It's tricky to build something that gets an accurate count since there's no way to truly identify a visitor without some type of login (which is a good thing from a privacy point of view). Using cookies is usually good enough since most people don't manually delete cookies. Otherwise, using a third party service, like Google Analytics, is usually your best bet. And since you seem to already have GA on the site (since you can compare the results), why reinvent the wheel on your site?

Comment: I can't say for sure what the diff is though, but it's very possible that bots are the reason for some. There are ways you can identify most common bots (you would need to google it though) so you could simply ignore tracking those and see if it makes a difference. Other than that, I don't really see any specific issue with your current code (unless people are accessing it in incognito mode, which removes cookies when you close the browser, but that's hard to account for).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sir I using google analytics but I want to learn how it works

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sir I have updated the code please let me know is it the right way and will it work?

Comment: AOL users share a set of IP addresses.